# Spring Boot - loading applicationContext.xml from external directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement on my project to load application context bean from the external directory(it should be managed via Java program arguments or "classpath" argument etc). The idea is that the JAR created with gradle does not contain applicationContext.xml, so it can be updated/replaced without re-building the JAR. My Spring boot application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My question is how I can achieve this? I tried to set -classpath argument to the directory location but it didn't work. I'm getting an exception on application startup(when I try to execute the JAR):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: For starters I would say this is a very bad idea, you don't want external users to mess around with your application configuration. They can easily break things and trust me they will. That being said, the Spring Reference guide has a whole section on [loading resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-resourceloader). In short don't use `classpath:` but simply use `file:` and point to the location the xml file is at. Or simply use a placholder (`${app.config}`) and specify it whilst starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

First check how actually your classpath look like.
You can do it by:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

and check is full (or relative path from where you start java command) path to your directory is there.

If it is fine

In main class instead of

```
SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
```

try

```
new SampleApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleApplication.class)).run(args);
```

Answer (score 0):

To load the applicationContext from external dir using

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"file:/yourfullpath/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SampleApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```